# Ho to get the values with latest time stamp in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, greatest-n-per-group

```
Id   ProductType  DebitCard        date
101          HR1          N  01/01/2015
*101         HR1          Y  01/02/2015
101          HR2          N  01/01/2015
*101         HR2          Y  02/01/2015
*101         HC1          Y  02/15/2015
*101         HC2          Y  02/15/2015
```

How to get all the rows where id is ='101' and the rows with only latest time stamp. The highlighted rows (`*`)

Comment: How to get all the rows where id is ='101' and the rows with only latest time stamp. The highlighted rows..

Comment: latest means recent timestamp?

Comment: Do you wants records with `101` _and_ the most recent, or `101` _or_ the most recent?

Comment: Id should be 101 and all product types(Product type should be recent one for example HR1 has two rows in that one was updated on 01/01/2015 and the other one was on 01/02/2015, I want the secone row alone where time stamp is more than the first one)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a groupwise maximum, with partitions of `Id, ProductType`. There are a couple of ways to do this, here's one, using a join back to a derived table of grouped maxima :

```
SELECT t.Id, t.ProductType, t.DebitCard, t.date
FROM MyTable t
JOIN (
  SELECT Id, ProductType, MAX(date) as date
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE Id = 101
  GROUP BY Id, ProductType) AS x
ON x.Id = t.Id AND t.ProductType = x.ProductType AND t.date = x.date;
```

Note that if there is more than one 'latest' row that all such rows will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem typically solved using window functions (which is usually faster than doing a self join with an aggregate)

```
select id, producttype, debitcard, date
from (
  select id, producttype, debitcard, date,
         row_number() over (partition by producttype order by date desc) as rn
  from the_table
  where id = 101
) t
where rn = 1
order by producttype;
```

If you want to return ties (i.e. multiple rows with the same "latest" date) you need to use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`

---

<sup>Btw: `date` is a horrible name for a column. It not only is a reserved word, it also does not document the meaning of the column. Is is "received date", a "release date", an "expiration date", something else?</sup>